# CSS - Have each item in a horizontal list have an equal share of the available padding

Tags: css, list, menu, width, autosize

Consider a simple CSS layout, where containing wrapper div defines a fixed width of 900 or so pixels, everything inside it therefore expands to 100% width.

In here, I have a navigation div, containing 1 UL and 6 list items, left-floated so they appear in a line horizontally.

Each list item should growing variably to fit its text contents exactly, but the spacing between each item should be shared so that the whole menu fits into the 100% space, such as:

```
------------------------------------------------------
-N-        -N-          -N-               -N-      -N-
- -        - -          - -               - -      - -
- -ITEM1111- -ITEM222222- -ITEM33333333333- -ITEM44- -   
- -        - -          - -               - -      - -
------------------------------------------------------
<-------------------- 100% -------------------------->
```

I hope that is illustrative! 'N' is constant but grows to fit the 100% width accordingly (i.e. for accessibility - someone increases the font size).

Happy to take alternative suggestions although I'm aiming for no javascript or images, just css purity.

Comment: Does the LI padding matter at all? If not then you might consider removing the reference to padding in your question title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my simple solution for this based on CSS3 [Flexible Box Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/):

**Styles**

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid Gray;
}

.flexmenu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
}

.flexmenu li {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;

    -webkit-flex-basis: auto;
    -moz-flex-basis: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:900px">
    <ul class="flexmenu">
        <li>short</li>
        <li>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</li>
        <li>short</li>
        <li>short</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: +1 for flexi-sexi but the problem stated that the list items should be as wide as they need. the space left from 900px should then be divided equally and used as the padding between each item..the padding is therefore the same width and the ul width = 900

Comment: In my example the second item is bigger, than others, and as you can see on the image, it takes as much space, as it needs, decreasing paddings respectively. I've specified `width: 400px;` here just for example. You can change it to any value and it will work.

Comment: @jenson-button-event I've updated answer to fit the question precisely.

Answer (score 4):

If IE6/IE7 compatibility is not critical to you, this layout is trivial using display: table

http://jsfiddle.net/5SFG5/

Comment: Your comment and your fiddle both fail to address the padding issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the padding issue" gordian. If you read the original question, it speaks in terms of width and spacing, not padding.

Comment: Your LIs do not have any padding, which the OP posed as a major point in the question. I don't see a way for them to all share in the available padding in your fiddle.

Comment: gordion, read the question. The word padding is only mentioned in the title, and the user wants the LIs spaced evenly.

Comment: Difficult to discern what the OP means by "padding".

Comment: Not really. He is referring to the extra space.

Comment: Even if he is not talking about box model padding, your fiddle breaks if any is applied to the anchor or list item.

Comment: As does the "accepted" answer. Or any pure CSS solution that doesn't override padding. But then, if a user applies padding to an li, it's part of the size of the li, isn't it? The extra space left over is still distributed evenly.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that when an element is floated, its width is reduced to the actual width of the content. You can toy with this using Javascript though (I know you requested a no-js version, but I can't think of another option). In jQuery it should be fairly easy. Given this structure:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li>ITEM1</li>
  <li>ITEM2</li>
  <li>ITEM3</li>
</ul>
```

you could do something like this:

```
var width = 0, maxwidth = 900;
$('#nav li').each(function(){
  width += $(this).width();
});
var count = 2 * $('#nav').size();
var margin = (maxwidth - width) / count;
$('#nav li').css({
  marginLeft: margin + 'px',
  marginRight: margin + 'px'
});
```

Sorry for the messy code, I'm in a bit of a hurry :D. Anyways, what you do is, basically: check the total width occupied by the `li` elements, check how much is unoccupied and fill it with `li` margins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how N can be both a constant and a variable width.

Here's a start..

CSS

```
#nav { width: 100%; display: inline; }
#nav ul li {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                margin: 2%;
                width: 10%;
            }

 #nav ul li a {margin: 0 auto; display: block;}
```

html

```
<div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
         </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: N is constant across all columns. N=100%-(width-of-all-columns)/number-of-columns